# Pasting to vim from clipboard cuts off first few lines

Tags: vim

I'm using vim in terminal on OSX with a blank .vimrc file. I try to paste the following from my clipboard:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -o pipefail

npm run precommit
```

using

```
:set paste
```

but in vim, what's pasted (using cmd-v) is

```
et -e
set -o pipefail

npm run precommit
```

Anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: did you forget to enter insert mode?

Comment: No, even entering insert mode before cmv-v'ing has the same result. EDIT: I tried doing it all over again and it worked. I dunno what I missed as I tried multiple times before posting here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to enter into insert mode before you can edit the file, you can do this by pressing the **i** key.

Comment: How come without entering insert mode, it will paste but not the entire chunk?

Comment: It enters in insert mode when it encounters a word like `i`, `o` etc in the pasted text.

Comment: If you don't enter insert mode Vim will execute each of the letters separately in normal mode, so in your case #!/bin/bash means: Look for the previous ocurrance of word (#), don't remember what the ! does in insert mode, (/) will start a search, then bin/bash will be the query for the search after the new line. Nothing will be found and then comes the second line "set -e" and the letter (s) means substitute which waits for input and enters insert mode, then the rest of your clipboard gets pasted

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using `vim` on OSX, you can add the following to your `.vimrc`:

`set clipboard+=unnamed`

Once you have done this, vim will use the system clipboard to read from by default for pasting. This means that, instead of having to enter `insert` mode first you can simply use `p` to paste. It also means that if you `y`ank within vim, it's available to paste elsewhere.

I haven't tested this on any other OS, so if anyone has please feel free to add a comment...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, the trick was to reset my terminal by typing 'reset' before running vim.